# Getting content type not found error in Visual Studio 2013 when deploying SharePoint 2013 solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, solution-package

I am deploying a SP2013 solution, and there is some custom content types to add. But I get the error:

```
Error   4   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Content type not found (Id: '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900A0DC9D823C31494295B223AFF0719867').
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: the error is coming from a feature. What does that feature do? Is it creating a list instance?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to answer without more data. But, apparently, there is a missing CT! :)

Get your hands on the ULS-logs during deployment and start there.

Then try removing feature elements from the feature one by one (if possible) to target the problem.